# Self-Cleaning an Oven to Kasher If Food Residue Remains

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, cleaning

From http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/623729/jewish/How-do-I-kosher-an-oven.htm: "If your oven is of the self-cleaning variety, koshering it is fairly simple. All you need to do is self-clean it". Is this — that no other cleaning needs to be done and the oven is kashered — true even if food residue remains after the cycle is completed?

Answer (score 1):

The food residue is burned to an ash and therefore is no longer *food residue*. It is better to clean out the ash, but that is more of a practical matter.

[LIBUN Gamur (Burning)](https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/kashering-for-passover/)

> Utensils used directly in the fire, (e.g. BBQ grate) must be kashered
>   by placing them into fire. This process has the effect of burning any
>   absorbed taste. To qualify as a complete libun, metal must be heated
>   until it glows. A self-clean cycle of an oven (approx. 850° F) also
>   qualifies as libun. There is no need to wait 24 hours before libun,
>   though it is advised. **There is no need to scrub the utensil before
>   performing libun, since the fire will burn off residue**, but some
>   cleaning is advised.